# What is returned when an attempt to retrieve a setting that is not in app.config

Tags: .net, settings, app-config

What is returned when a setting is called from code but is not in the app.config file. Is it null?

Comment: Seems like something that would be simple to try ... ?

Comment: Sounds like a great test question :)

Comment: Oh gee thanks for the down votes guys! The only reason I ask is because I don't have access to my Dev environment and I'm on site messing with a customer config...

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer you're looking for is NULL btw.  Sorry for the comment earlier too.  ( I put in an upvote for you )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`.

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d0bzeeb.aspx): (NameValueCollection.Item Property)

> Property Value
>
> Type: System.String
>
> A String that contains the comma-separated list of
> values associated with the specified key, if found; otherwise, null.